# count upper and lowercase letters in python using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tuples, uppercase, lowercase

I need help coming up with this python function.
A recursive function count_upper_lower() that takes a non-empty string as its argument and returns a tuple containing the counts of how many letters in the string are uppercase and how many are lowercase (in that order).
For instance

```
print (count_upper_lower(’Town Hall University’))
```

would return

```
(3, 15)
```

this is what i have so far

```
def count_upper_lower(word):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    if word == "":
        upper = 0
        lower = 0
        return upper, lower
    elif word[0].isupper():
        upper = 1 + count_upper_lower(word[1:])
        return upper , lower


    elif word[0].islower():
        lower = 1 + count_upper_lower(word[1:])
        return upper , lower

    else:
        upper = 0 + count_upper_lower(word[1:])
        lower = 0 + count_upper_lower(word[1:])
        return upper, lower
```

i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Hint: go through the call for `word=="a"`. What do you expect `1 + (0, 0)` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, you're trying to add ints to tuples, which is why you are getting the error message. Consider the following example instead:

```
def count_upper_lower(word):
    if not word:
        return 0, 0
    else:
        upper, lower = count_upper_lower(word[1:])
        if word[0].isupper():
            return upper+1, lower
        elif word[0].islower():
            return upper, lower+1
        else:
            # make sure that this is what you want
            return upper, lower
```

Here, the function recursively calls itself until the string is used up. The else case catches the case that the character is neither an upper nor a lower character (e.g. a digit), in which case neither counter is increased.

Comment: This returns exactly what i needed. My tuple addition was not right. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop and ascii. In the ascii table 65 untill 91 is a upper case and 97 untill 123 is a lower case.

```
def count_upper_lower(word):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for letter in word: #runs through all the letter if empty nothing happens
       if 65 <= ord(letter) <= 90:
           upper += 1
       elif 97 <= ord(letter) <= 122:
           lower += 1
    return upper,lower
```

This is also possible.

```
def count_upper_lower(word):
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    for letter in word: #runs through all the letter if empty nothing happens
       if letter.isupper():
           upper += 1
       elif letter.islower():
           lower += 1
    return upper,lower
```

Comment: was just about to post a similar solution, this is the right approach imo

Comment: That's not recursive, and I think OP's suggestion of using the `isupper` and `islower` methods is more pythonic than using the ASCII character identifiers.

Comment: Thanks but it has to be recursion

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with two lines of code:

```
lst = [1 if letter.islower() else 0 for letter in word if letter.islower() or letter.isupper()]
print (lst.count(0),lst.count(1))
```

Comment: I challenge everyone to make it in one line

Comment: Just replace lst with list comprehension in the print statement :D Stupid, but 1 line

Comment: That is indeed stupid, but you are right it is one line

Answer (score 0):

In your else block, you are trying to add the returning tuple from count_upper_lower() to a number.

```
class myCounter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lower = 0
        self.upper = 0

    def count(self, s):
        if not s:
            return (self.upper, self.lower)

        firstCharacter = s[0]

        if firstCharacter.islower():
            self.lower += 1
        elif firstCharacter.isupper():
            self.upper += 1
        else:
            pass #do nothing !

        return self.count(s[1:])


c = myCounter()
print(c.count("Town Hall University"))
>>> (3, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with using `tuple` as it's an immutable data structure. Used `list` instead.

```
def count_letters(phrase):
    if phrase:
        letter = phrase[0]
        result = count_letters(phrase[1:])
        if letter.isupper():
            result[0] += 1
        elif letter.islower():
            result[1] += 1
        return result
    else:
        return [0, 0]


>>> count_letters("LaLaa")
[2, 3]
```